# how to find documentation or readable source code of gapy.pyd in arcpy?

Tags: python, arcpy

I want to rewrite an **ArcGis** tool script, which is called `Multi-Distance Spatial Cluster Analysis（Ripleys K Function)`. But when I read the source code of this tool script in Pycharm, I find a module named "gapy", I can not click it and read the source code just like other modules.

The functions of this pyd file seem to deal with the data structure of a `Shape` file in ArcGis, so it is very important for me to understand.

Well I know this module is a pyd file actually, I have searched online and it seems that we can not read a pyd file directly. So I searched in the ArcGis official website to find the documentation of this file, but I failed.

```
import gapy as GAPY # this line can be found in tool script
```

I expect to find a way to understand how to use this module. Anyone can help me? Thanks very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If this is a vendor shipped module, you are out of luck. They won't provide you with source code. And if it's a PYD file, chances are that the source is not even Python, but C or C++ or whatever. The only thing you can do is to ask the vendor for *documentation* (somebody had to write the tool script and learned what the calls are for).